# AngularJS nested items by subcategory server-side

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, pagination

I am improving a custom application that was built using AngularJS with NodeJS/sails and MongoDB.

The data is curently shown on the page with ng-repeat elements. There is no pagination, so the site slows to a crawl if there is a lot of data on the page.

I need to add pagination, but the problem is the way the data is being shown is not very efficient, as explained below.

We have data stored in the following format. Subcategories are stored in one collection and Items are stored in another collection. Each Item has a subcategory ID that references the relevant subcategory.

```
//Subcategories
{
"_id" : ObjectId("56e1b10e90ea9b0500137555"),
"subcategory_name" : "Signature Sandwiches",
"caterer_id" : "56e1a2b690ea9b0500137552",
"category_id" : "56b09346b1eb22cc25698030"
}

{
"_id" : ObjectId("56e084c97b2d6c060008b378"),
"subcategory_name" : "Platters",
"caterer_id" : "56e1a2b690ea9b0500137552",
"category_id" : "56b09346b1eb22cc2569802f"
}

//Items
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5612fsca7b2d6c123458b3fd"),
"item_name" : "Turkey and Swiss",
"item_price" : "7.50",
"caterer_id" : "56e084b07b2d6c060008b374",
"subcategory_id" : "56e1b10e90ea9b0500137555",
}

{
"_id" : ObjectId("5612fsca7b2d6c123458b3fd"),
"item_name" : "Roast Beef and Cheddar",
"item_price" : "5.50",
"caterer_id" : "56e084b07b2d6c060008b374",
"subcategory_id" : "56e1b10e90ea9b0500137555",
}

{
"_id" : ObjectId("5612fsc10c739c123458b3fd"),
"item_name" : "Grilled Cheese",
"item_price" : "3.50",
"caterer_id" : "56e084b07b2d6c060008b374",
"subcategory_id" : "56e1b10e90ea9b0500137555",
}

{
"_id" : ObjectId("56e084ca7b2d6c060008b3fd"),
"item_name" : "Teacake Platter",
"item_price" : "3.50",
"caterer_id" : "56e084b07b2d6c060008b374",
"subcategory_id" : "56e084c97b2d6c060008b378",
}

{
"_id" : ObjectId("56e084ca7b2d6c060008b3fe"),
"item_name" : "Appetizer Platter",
"item_price" : "4.75",
"caterer_id" : "56e084b07b2d6c060008b374",
"subcategory_id" : "56e084c97b2d6c060008b378"
}
```

I want the data to be displayed with the subcategory name and the relevant items underneath each subcategory name.

**Desired Output**

Signature Sandwiches

- Turkey and Swiss
- Roast Beef and Cheddar
- Grilled Cheese

Platters

- Teacake Platter
- Appetizer Platter

The previous developers got this to work but they are doing so very inefficiently. There is a method that pulls ALL the items and then the browser filters out the results by using an ng-if.

```
<div ng-repeat="subcategory in subcategories">
   <tr ng-repeat="item in items" ng-if="subcategory.id==item.subcategory_id">
```

The back-end code is a mess, but basically there is a method that is called at the top of the page that gathers all subcategories and items and sets them to variables that are bound directly to $scope. Thus data is all made available globally and then it is referenced in the DOM.

Instead, I want the Items to be filtering by Subcategory to happen on the server-side and that way I can build arrays of objects that are relevant to each subcategory. Then I can probably figure out the pagination more easily.

Comment: Not to clear what you are actually asking here. You possibly want [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) on the server side, however you appear to have managed to store things like `"category_id"` and `"subcategory_id"` as "strings" as opposed to the correct `ObjectId` format. This is a problem for "references" since the types between those properties and he `"_id"` properties they "refer" to are actually different. You need to fix your data first so that all are in fact `ObjectId`.

Comment: Takes a lot less storage that way as well. 12-bytes for `ObjectId` compared to 26-bytes for the "string".

Comment: Good point, I'll look into that... this is an existing project that I am "inheriting" from developers in India. Thanks for your suggestion.